# NodeJS get a count of bytes of streaming file download

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, stream

In this code I stream a file from a url and save it to a file. Is there a way to also pipe it through something that will count the number of bytes piped? (Which would tell me the file size.)

```
  request.stream(url)
    .pipe(outputFile)
```

Is there some library that would do this by piping the download through it, or a simple way for me to do it myself?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it like this with [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library:

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

var downloaded = 0;
request.get(url)
  .on('data', function(chunk){
    downloaded += chunk.length;
    console.log('downloaded', downloaded);
  })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName));
```

Also, you can check [this link](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) to learn how to do it without `request` package.

#### Update #1 (Pure NodeJS solution)

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var download = function(url, dest, cb) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  var downloaded = 0;
  var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    response.on('data', function(chunk){
      downloaded += chunk.length;
      console.log(downloaded);
    })
    file.on('finish', function() {
      file.close(cb);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `request` example. Would you mind providing an example also of how to do it without the request package based on that link you provided?

Comment: `file.on('finish'…` should be `file.on('end'…`

Comment: In case of deflated pages, is there a way to count bytes before inflating? (any  http module, or pure node)

Answer (score 2):

With typings and byteLength property:

```
const stream: ReadStream = file.createReadStream(); 
const chunks: Buffer[] = [];
let fileSize = 0;

stream.on('data', (chunk: Buffer) => {
  fileSize += chunk.byteLength;

  chunks.push(chunk);
});

stream.once('end', () => {
  const fileBuffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);

  console.log('equal values:', fileBuffer.byteLength === fileSize);
});
```