# NodeJS - Watching for space when streaming data to zipped file

Tags: node.js, events, pipe, gzip, diskspace

I am creating a zipped file with NodeJS streams using the following snippet.

```js
  let gzip = zlib.createGzip()

  let wstream = fs.createWriteStream('/some/filename')
  console.log('Writing to /some/filename')
  dataStream // Someone is writing to this stream
    .pipe(someTransform)
    .pipe(gzip)
    .pipe(wstream)
    .on('close', () => { // Someone has done a dataStream.end() and a dataStream.destroy()
      someTransform.unpipe(gzip).unpipe(wstream)
      someTransform.destroy()
      gzip.destroy()
      wstream.destroy()
      console.log('Finished writing to /some/filename')}
```

I would like to know, if I can handle an event of low disk space gracefully. Suppose, if `/some` has reached 95% limit, then, I would like to stop streaming at that point than having whole of the process crash due to no space on device.

There is a `ENOSPC` [constant](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_posix_error_constants); but, I am not sure, how to handle this error while streaming.

Comment: One approach is to measure available disk space up front, then count the number of bytes as you stream.  When the number of bytes is close to exceeding the available disk space, gracefully exit.

Comment: Can you please show me an example of how do we count bytes as we stream and check against a threshold?

Comment: `chunk.length` should do... https://stackoverflow.com/a/43548442/919480